# No me genera el pdf que deseo en Google Chrome

Tags: php, fpdf

Tengo un pequeño problema con la herramienta FPDF en mi sitio web, la cosa es que en localhost todo funciona perfectamente, pero al llevar mi php al hosting online y solicitar el pdf la página se queda en blanco totalmente, sin imprimir ningún resultado o error.

mi código php es el siguiente:

```
 <?php

require('fpdf.php');



$pdf=new FPDF();

$pdf->AddPage();



$pdf->Line(20,20,190,20);


$pdf->Image('../imagenes/logo.png',10,6,30);
$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','B',35);

$pdf->Cell(0,40,'ORDEN DE COMPRA',0,1,'C');



$pdf->Line(20,38,190,38);

$pdf->Rect(20,38,100,14);

$pdf->Rect(120,38,70,14);



$conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost','id5532765_martita_admin','969895752','id5532765_martita');



$compras=mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT cliente.nombres,apellidos, compras.num_venta,nombre,imagen,cantidad,precio,psubtotal,fecha,direccion,celular FROM cliente INNER JOIN compras ON cliente.id_usuario=compras.id_usuario WHERE num_venta=".$_GET['num_venta']);

$numeroventa=0;

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($compras)){

if($numeroventa!=$row['num_venta']){

$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','B',23);

$pdf->Cell(12);

$pdf->Cell(0,-9,utf8_decode('PEDIDO N°'.$row['num_venta']),0,1,'L');



$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','B',23);

$pdf->Cell(125);

$pdf->Cell(0,9,utf8_decode($row['fecha']),0,1,'L');



//Nombre

$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','B',14);

$pdf->Cell(10);

$pdf->Cell(0,25,utf8_decode("SOLICITADO(A) POR:"),0,1,'L');



$pdf->Rect(75,58,115,8);

$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','',14);

$pdf->Cell(67);

$pdf->Cell(0,-25,utf8_decode($row['nombres']."\n".$row['apellidos']),0,1,'L');



//Direccion

$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','B',14);

$pdf->Cell(10);

$pdf->Cell(0,49,utf8_decode("DIRECCIÓN:"),0,1,'L');



$pdf->Rect(52,70,138,8);

$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','',14);

$pdf->Cell(43);

$pdf->Cell(0,-49,utf8_decode($row['direccion']),0,1,'L');



//Celular

$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','B',14);

$pdf->Cell(10);

$pdf->Cell(0,73,utf8_decode("CELULAR O TELÉFONO DE REFERENCIA:"),0,1,'L');



$pdf->Rect(124,82,66,8);

$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','',14);

$pdf->Cell(115);

$pdf->Cell(0,-73,utf8_decode($row['celular']),0,1,'L');



$pdf->Ln(44);

//Comentario



//Tabla

$pdf->Ln(22);

$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','B',11);

$pdf->Cell(11,5,'',0,'C',false);

$pdf->Cell(85,10,utf8_decode("DESCRIPCIÓN DEL PRODUCTO"),1,0,'L',false);

$pdf->Cell(17,10,'CANT.',1,0,'C',false);

$pdf->Cell(32,10,'PRECIO UNIT.',1,0,'C',false);

$pdf->Cell(35,10,'PRECIO TOTAL',1,0,'C',false);



}

$numeroventa=$row['num_venta'];

//Parte de los detalles

$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','',10);

$pdf->Ln(10);

$pdf->Cell(11,5,'',0,'C',false);

$pdf->Cell(85,10,utf8_decode($row[3]),1,0,'L',false);

$pdf->Cell(17,10,$row[5],1,0,'C',false);

$pdf->Cell(32,10,'S/.'.number_format($row[6], 2, '.', ''),1,0,'R',false);

$pdf->Cell(35,10,'S/.'.number_format($row[7], 2, '.', ''),1,0,'R',false);

}



$conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost','id5532765_martita_admin','969895752','id5532765_martita');



$sumar=mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT SUM(psubtotal) AS suma FROM compras WHERE num_venta=".$_GET['num_venta']);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sumar)){

//Total

$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','B',11);

$pdf->Ln(10);

$pdf->Cell(11,5,'',0,'C',false);

$pdf->Cell(134,10,'TOTAL A PAGAR:',1,0,'C',false);

$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','',10);

$pdf->Cell(35,10,'S/.'.number_format($row['suma'], 2, '.', ''),1,0,'R',false);

}



$conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost','id5532765_martita_admin','969895752','id5532765_martita');



$compras=mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT cliente.nombres,apellidos, compras.num_venta,nombre,imagen,cantidad,precio,psubtotal,fecha,direccion,celular FROM cliente INNER JOIN compras ON cliente.id_usuario=compras.id_usuario WHERE num_venta=".$_GET['num_venta']);

$numeroventa=0;

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($compras)){

if($numeroventa!=$row['num_venta']){

$pdf->Output('I', utf8_decode('PEDIDO N°'.$row['num_venta'].'.pdf'));

}

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Por mi experiencia, el problema con FPDF es que si se ha enviado "algo" (lo que sea, aunque sea un espacio en blanco) al navegador antes de usar el método `Output()`, lanza un error y no muestra el pdf.
Probablemente, tu hosting tenga desactivada la salida de errores, por cuestiones de seguridad (la directiva `display_errors` de `php.ini`). Si es un hosting compartido, no puedes modificar esa configuración en el servidor, y el proveedor no te la va a cambiar.

Sin embargo, si hay varias cosas que puedes hacer. Lo primero es iniciar tu código cambiando esa directiva en tiempo de ejecución, así:

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

Eso activa la visualización de errores para ese script concreto. Comprueba entonces si FPDF te muestra un error diciendo que ya se ha enviado contenido al navegador y no puede generar el pdf. El error está en inglés, claro, pero es muy fácil de comprender. No recuerdo la frase exacta que aparece, pero se entiende el problema a partir de ella.

Si es ese el problema (que suele ser lo más habitual), empieza por quitar todas las tabulaciones y saltos de línea innecesarios en tu código. Por ejemplo (reproduciendo un fragmento de tu propio código):

```
$pdf->Cell(35,10,'S/.'.number_format($row['suma'], 2, '.', ''),1,0,'R',false);

}



$conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost','id5532765_martita_admin','969895752','id5532765_martita');



$compras=mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT cliente.nombres,apellidos, compras.num_venta,nombre,imagen,cantidad,precio,psubtotal,fecha,direccion,celular FROM cliente INNER JOIN compras ON cliente.id_usuario=compras.id_usuario WHERE num_venta=".$_GET['num_venta']);
```

Sutitúyelo por:

```
$pdf->Cell(35,10,'S/.'.number_format($row['suma'], 2, '.', ''),1,0,'R',false);
}
$conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost','id5532765_martita_admin','969895752','id5532765_martita');
$compras=mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT cliente.nombres,apellidos, compras.num_venta,nombre,imagen,cantidad,precio,psubtotal,fecha,direccion,celular FROM cliente INNER JOIN compras ON cliente.id_usuario=compras.id_usuario WHERE num_venta=".$_GET['num_venta']);
```

Con eso se solucionan la mayoría de los problemas de este tipo (que, por cierto, con FPDF nos han pasado a todos al principio).

Una forma de ver si te está introduciendo saltos de línea es hacer clic derecho sobre la página esa en blanco que te sale, y pulsar en ver el código fuente de la página. Una vez que se te abra, clic derecho sobre el código fuente, y Seleccionar todo. Si te aparece seleccionado aunque sea un espacio o un salto de línea, ya sabes de donde viene el problema.

Si necesitas alguna aclaración dímelo, y trataré de ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Metiste la sentencia

```
$pdf->Output('I', utf8_decode('PEDIDO N°'.$row['num_venta'].'.pdf'));
```

Dentro de un bucle.

La salida debe ser única y la última antes de terminar el script o antes de un die:.